# Load some CSS with style-loader and some CSS with to-string-loader in Webpack 2

Tags: css, angular, webpack-style-loader, webpack-2

I'm working on an Angular 2 app and currently trying to build it with Webpack 2 (this is my first foray into Webpack).

I understand the difference between `style-loader` and `to-string-loader`, the former adds CSS to the DOM, the latter creates a string array for Angular 2 to consume via the `styles` property.

My question is, can I have both? Or put another way, if I have global styles in a file `site.css`, what is the proper way to bundle those with Webpack without changing the behavior for component styles (`to-string-loader`, `css-loader`)?

Just requiring or importing them in `main.ts` doesn't seem to be enough for Webpack to figure out what to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loaders [can be overridden](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html#loader-order) for specific module request:

```
require("!!style!css!./global-styles/site.css");
```

Or different loaders [can be defined for different conditions](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders):

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "global-styles")],
            loaders: ['style', 'css']
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, "global-styles")],
            loaders: ['to-string', 'css']
        },
    ...
```